# GZipStream: Compressed file bigger than original

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I'm trying to use gzip streams in C# but it appears that the files after compression are bigger than before. 
It's occurs when I working with .avi and .mkv files. But if I working with .txt and .html compressed file smaller than original.

```
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream(blockToCompress.Length))
{
     using (GZipStream cs = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
     {
          cs.Write(blockToCompress, 0, blockToCompress.Length);
     }
}
```

I solved this problem by checking the Framework (from 3.5 to 4.0) without editing the code.

Comment: (Most) video files are already heavily compressed, so that recompression will often increase their size. English text is very compressible.

Comment: This is a repeated question please refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973485/can-gzip-compression-via-net-increase-file-size

Comment: If those formats could be compressed further, than all video providers(like youtube) stream them in that format.

Comment: The .NET compression code is awful. Use an external lib to at least stay very close to 100% for incompressible data.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. Unfortunately, your expectations are not.

Most video and audio files are already heavily compressed. They won't be able to be compressed any further with [lossless compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) like GZip. In fact, you might slightly increase file size - every file format, GZip included, carried with it some overhead/bookkeeping.

If you truly need to reduce their size, you'll need to use a [lossy compression scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) that comprehends the video format. Basically, you'll be removing data, probably reducing apparent quality, in exchange for a smaller size.

Lossless compression schemes like GZip can reduce file size by 25-50%, if the source content is uncompressed. Files with lots of repeated text (HTML) or English text (general text files) usually compress much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your avi and mkv files is as most media formats already heavily compressed, gzip is likely not able too compress them any further, the size increase is a but weird but according to gzip specification there is at least a header flag byte and depending on the implementation it might add some more metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Assume a loseless compression algorithm would be able to compress every file. With that you can just compress the compressed output again and get an even smaller file, ultimately you could compress every file to size zero if you just compressed it again and again. This is obviously not the case and the reason for that lies in information theoretical principles. But that also implies that for every compression algorithm there are files that can not be compressed or that will grow due to compression. Finally the files that will grow due to compression are files that have high entropy and compressed video files belong to this category and this explains what you are seeing.