# Zlib compression in Powershell

Tags: powershell, zlib, system.io.compression

I need to compress a string to Zlib in PowerShell.

Is there a way we can compress using the ZLibStream class in PowerShell?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zlibstream?view=net-8.0

I was able to compress using the class `DeflateStream` and `GZipStream`, but the external system which uses the data was not able to decode it.

This is the powershell script I tried with

```
$stringToCompress  = 'string to compress'

$memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$deflateStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GZipStream($memStream, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)
$streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($deflateStream)
$streamWriter.Write($stringToCompress)
$streamWriter.Close();
$encodedCompressedString = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($memStream.ToArray())
Write-Output $encodedCompressedString
```

Comment: Possible duplicatie with: [zlib compressing byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282575/zlib-compressing-byte-array) ?

Comment: @Luuk, the linked post predates .NET 6+ (.NET Core altogether), so it doesn't discuss the type of interest here, [`ZLibStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zlibstream).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of compression and expansion with `ZLibStream` is pretty much the same as with [`GZipStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=net-8.0).

Note that `ZlibStream` only works with .NET 6+ meaning that it is not available for Windows PowerShell 5.1 (.NET Framework 4.5+). If you want to use this class you will need to install [PowerShell 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

```bash
# Choose encoding here, need to use the same for compress & decompress
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

# - Compress:
$string = 'hello world!'

$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$zlib = [System.IO.Compression.ZLibStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)

$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($string)
$zlib.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$zlib.Dispose()

[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($outstream.ToArray())
# eJzLSM3JyVcozy/KSVEEAB6JBH4=

# - Decompress:
$instream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new(
    [System.Convert]::FromBase64String('eJzLSM3JyVcozy/KSVEEAB6JBH4='))

$zlib = [System.IO.Compression.ZLibStream]::new(
    $instream,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)

$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$zlib.CopyTo($outstream)
$zlib.Dispose()
$enc.GetString($outstream.ToArray())
# hello world!
```

---

An alternative for Windows PowerShell 5.1 can be to use the [`ZLibWrapper` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Joveler.ZLibWrapper).

First download the package and expand it:

```bash
$invokeWebRequestSplat = @{
    OutFile = 'Joveler.ZLibWrapper.zip'
    Uri     = 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Joveler.ZLibWrapper'
}
Invoke-WebRequest @invokeWebRequestSplat
Expand-Archive 'Joveler.ZLibWrapper.zip'
```

Then the flow is pretty similar using their assembly:

```bash
Add-Type -Path .\Joveler.ZLibWrapper\lib\net45\Joveler.ZLibWrapper.dll

# Choose encoding here, need to use the same for compress & decompress
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

# - Compress:
$string = 'hello world!'

$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$zlib = [Joveler.ZLibWrapper.ZlibStream]::new(
    $outstream,
    [Joveler.ZLibWrapper.ZLibMode]::Compress)

$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($string)
$zlib.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$zlib.Dispose()

[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($outstream.ToArray())

# - Decompress:
$instream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new(
    [System.Convert]::FromBase64String('eJzLSM3JyVcozy/KSVEEAB6JBH4='))

$zlib = [Joveler.ZLibWrapper.ZLibStream]::new(
    $instream,
    [Joveler.ZLibWrapper.ZLibMode]::Decompress)

$outstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$zlib.CopyTo($outstream)
$zlib.Dispose()
$enc.GetString($outstream.ToArray())
# hello world!
```

Answer (score -2):

My answer is similar to other answers.  I spent lots of time debugging.  Found major issue with the sample code at MSDN not flushing the stream and I got no results.  The dispose in other answers does a flush and close and will get results.  He is my code with flush and close.

Note : The only thing wrong with OPs original Posting is the missing Flush.

```
$message = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($message)

$writeStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::New()
$compressor = [System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream]::New($writeStream, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress, $true)
$compressor.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$compressor.Flush()
$compressor.Close()

$writeStream.Position = 0
$finalStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::New()
$decompressor = [System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream]::New($writeStream, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress, $true);
$decompressor.CopyTo($finalStream)
$decompressor.Flush()
$decompressor.Close()
$finalStream.Position = 0
$bytes = [byte[]]::New($finalStream.Length)
$numberBytes = $finalStream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)
$results = $enc.GetString($bytes)
$results
```

Comment: "I was able to compress using the class DeflateStream and GZipStream, but the external system which uses the data was not able to decode it." Is what OP states in his question

Comment: Leaving aside that OP's code has no issues, calling `.Close()` calls `.Flush()` internally and calling `.Dispose()` calls `.Close()` internally.

Comment: The Compression Level may solve issue.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=net-8.0#remarks